# Loopback default values for missing properties when fetching data from MongoDB

Tags: loopbackjs

How should I define the Loopback model so that all the properties listed in the model JSON file would always appear on the result even when those properties have no value (or are missing) from the MongoDB record? Should this behaviour be configured in the Loopback or in the MongoDB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a Schema-less database. It is designed in this way to give us flexibility for adding new fields to a document without any need to restart the database. So I don't think that it is a good idea to handle this scenario on the database side.

I think the best way to handle this could be setting a default value for every property in LoopBack model definition.  This solution has a problem when some data is inserted into the database from outside the project.
You can also handle missing parameter at the front-end side.

Another solution that I can think of, is implementing an afterRemote method for checking the existence of all the fields. In this case, you can use this function after any API route that you want to. You can check the following link for more information:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html#signature